# Как обратится к массиву из другого класса

Tags: java

Есть классы Program, Channel,TV В TV есть метод включения телевизора. Он включает канал, как сделать что бы вывести еще и программу котора в массиве Program programs[]; (включен канал 1 с программаой такой то)

```
 public class Program {
String name;

ublic class Channel {
String name;
Program programs[];

public class TV {
String modelTV;
Channel channnels[];
RemoteController remote;}

public String getModelTV() {
    return modelTV;
}
public void setModelTV(String modelTV) {
    this.modelTV = modelTV;
}
public void setChannnels(Channel[] channnels) {
    this.channnels = channnels;
}
public void setRemote(RemoteController remote) {
    this.remote = remote;
}

public TV(String modelTV) {
    this.modelTV = modelTV;
}

public Channel[] getChannnels() {
    return channnels;
}

public void tvOn(int channelNumber){
     for (int i = 0 ; i<channnels.length ; i++){
        if (i==channelNumber) {
            System.out.println("Включен :"+channnels[i].name);
                return; }
   }
      System.out.println("Канал с номером " + channelNumber + " не найден!");}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 Program program1=new Program("Спорт");
 Program program2=new Program("Новости");
 Program program3=new Program("Кино");
 Program program4=new Program("Животные");
 Channel channel1=new Channel("Первый канал");
 Channel channel2=new Channel("Второй канал");
 channel1.setPrograms(new Program[]{program1,program2});
 channel2.setPrograms(new Program[]{program3,program4});
 TV tv=new TV("RUBIN");
 tv.setChannnels(new Channel[]{channel1,channel2});
  tv.tvOn(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное так:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<channnels.length ; i++){
    if (i==channelNumber) {
        System.out.println("Включен :"+channnels[i].name);
        System.out.println("Программы:");

        for (int j = 0 ; j < channnels[i].programs.length ; j++){
            System.out.print(channnels[i].programs[j].name);
        }
            return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо проверю, тоже думал про второй циккл, но не смог из за молодости )

Comment: у меня почему то выводит программы слитно и две сразу СпортНовости

Comment: @Mobsman потому что написано `print`. Выводите с пробелом в конце, если надо